# Bone snaps back to its original position when setting new keys

Tags: animation, bones, keyframes

This is the only blend file that functions weirdly. I am animating a rig and when I grab a bone to move or rotate it, it immediately snaps back to the previous key.

This is what I did:

1. In pose mode, insert a new keyframe on any bone (let's use root for this example), then move forward a couple of frames
2. With the bone still selected (again, it's the root bone)
3. Press G or R to grab or rotate
4. Press LMB to confirm the translation/rotation
5. **Bam!** It snaps back to its latest key (like when you hit RMB to cancel the action)

It would work 'normally' if I hit LMB and then quickly dragged the mouse the side. However, it's driving me crazy and it only seems to be breaking in this Blend file; other files work normally. I also tried to create a blank file to append the rig to that new file, but, the rig still functions weirdly.

If you guys can help me it would be fantastic :) thank you in advance!

This is the file:
http://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/86352

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the way to literally fix the problem! YAY!

So what I did was with the armature selected, go to Object tab and scroll down until I see Duplication tab. In my case, 'Frames' was selected and I simply changed to 'None' and the problem is now resolved.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another clue, can be an other constraint is on the chain and conflicts.
In this case, you have 2 bones colored in yellow in the chain.
So delete or fit conflicting constraint.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is caused by a script.

Open the text editor. You will see multiple scripts, which are causing problems.
[image: multiple images]

To remove a text file, open it and <kbd>Shift</kbd> click the X button.

[image]

The datablock *Text.003* seems to be close to a duplicate of RigUI.py. After removing all items except RigUI.py and reloading the file, the problem is removed.

Comment: I really appreciated your answer but I did try and nothing changed :( First I unlinked every script except the RigUI.py and reload Blender, but the problem still retained, Then I tried to delete RigUI.py (then saved the file) too but when I closed and reloaded the problem is still there :(

Comment: I see you solved it now. In my case it simply worked after my steps. Sorry.

Comment: No no don't be! You guided me to the right way and that's what I really appreciate :) Thank you again for answering my question!