# Bones don't move after editing

Tags: bones

When I transform a bone in any way (on an imported SMD) in pose mode, it moves back to its original position when I return to the frame. This essentially means I can't do anything, since no transformations are permanent.

It's the [same problem as the one here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/69069/bone-snaps-back-to-its-original-position-when-setting-new-keys) , but I tried his solution and many others without success.

Comment: dis you set any keyframes?

Comment: @cegaton (I forget to mention it's animated) There were already lots set so I didn't realise I'd have to; however, wouldn't this mean I'd have to set keyframes for every frame I change? is it possible to apply the same transformation to a bone over every keyframe?